# How does Live Lyrics work in content recognition

Tags: android, json, python-2.7, audio-fingerprinting

Alot of song identification platforms have been offering a feature to display Live synchronized lyrics of the recognized song. This involves displaying the lyrics and highlighting the part of the lyrics that is currently playing on the song in realtime.

It might also involve use of a corresponding lyrics file with timestamps showing which line to highlight. Example an LRC file

How can one use the meta data from the recognition results to implement this.
Here is an example of recognition results

```
recognizing by file ...
{"status":{"msg":"Success","code":0,"version":"1.0"},"metadata":{"music":[{"external_ids":{"isrc":"USAT21500254","upc":"075679928634"},"play_offset_ms":46360,"external_metadata":{"spotify":{"album":{"id":"0HfAFdxzAEOn1H9WQeaqgZ"},"artists":[{"id":"6VuMaDnrHyPL1p4EHjYLi7"},{"id":"6JL8zeS1NmiOftqZTRgdTz"}],"track":{"id":"1zxFtsKWwuVpz3nSqNYshe"}},"deezer":{"album":{"id":9602354},"artists":[{"id":1362735}],"genres":[{"id":132}],"track":{"id":94424876}}},"label":"Artist Partners","release_date":"2015-02-10","title":"Marvin Gaye (feat. Meghan Trainor)","duration_ms":"187741","album":{"name":"Marvin Gaye (feat. Meghan Trainor)"},"acrid":"aa1c08067d9e3071f8a4d319fc186cb3","genres":[{"name":"Pop"}],"artists":[{"name":"Charlie Puth"}]}],"timestamp_utc":"2015-12-01 09:41:32"},"result_type":0}
```

Comment: I think it has to do with "play_offset_ms", "duration_ms" and possibly "timestamp_utc"

Answer (score 0):

You need lyrics with time stamps, e.g. a LRC file.

```
"[00:15]There's rain on the mountain"
```

You can display this sentence at

```
timestamp_utc - play_offset_ms + 15 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks @marmouset. Understood